# arm-zephyr-eabi-g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '-arch'; did you mean '-march='?

Tags: macos, cmake, zephyr-rtos

When we tried to build a Zephyr project in Mac Mini M2, we're getting this issue.

`arm-zephyr-eabi-g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '-arch'; did you mean '-march='?`

Tried setting,

1. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=armv8.5-a")`
2. `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ARM)`

in project top level CMakeLists.txt and no changes.

Any idea on how we can address this?

Comment: `fgrep -e -arch *` might help.

Comment: So this returns the system arch?

Comment: no, this shows you the file which defines the unrecognized option.

Comment: Gave it a try and it iterates through and says all are directory.

Comment: It might be in a subdirectory. Where can I download the source code you are trying to compile?

Comment: https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/2.4.2/nrf/applications/machine_learning/README.html

You may need nRF Connect SDK and toolchain setup if not already.

Comment: Nordic engineers patched this, PR: https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf/pull/12340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying [this](https://github.com/nrfconnect/sdk-nrf/pull/12340) patch resolved this.